# Bootstrap Cards responsive text that stacks correctly

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm trying to stack items in Bootstrap correctly. I'm using a container and rows to stack. After a certain breakpoint the items down't align correctly anymore. I want to fix that and checked all StackOverflow questions about cards and text but couldn't find any similar problem

Here the nearly correct design that works before 990px breakpoint (I would need to add some negative padding here so that the 0.x would align under the withdrawal):

[image]

After this breakpoint you'll get:

[image]

And the mobile version is completely wrong even though there would be enough space:

[image]

My code is in react/ nextjs so ignore the className if you aren't familiar with it

```
<div className="container">
      <div className="card-deck">
        {/*     CARD START */}
        <div className="card mb-4">
          <img
            className="card-img-top img-fluid"
            src="//placehold.it/500x280"
            alt="Card image cap"
          />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h4 className="card-title">Test information</h4>
            <div className="fee-stats">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-sm">
                    <p className="card-text">
                      TAKER
                      <br />
                      0.05%
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm">
                    <p className="card-text">
                      MAKER <br /> 0.05%
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm">
                    <p className="card-text">
                      WITHDRAWL
                      <br /> 0.0005
                      <span className="bitcoin-icon">&#8383;</span>{" "}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="card-footer border-0 rounded-bottom">
            <small className="text-muted">Intermediate</small>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-style {
          margin: auto;
          width: 80%;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        .card-img-top {
          margin: auto;
          width: 30%;
          padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .card-title {
          text-align: center;
        }
        .card-footer {
          background-color: #9effaf;
        }
        .rounded {
          border-radius: 0.6rem !important;
        }
        .rounded-bottom {
          border-bottom-left-radius: 0.6rem !important;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0.6rem !important;
        }
        .card-text {
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 65%;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your problem/desire completely but by specifying the width of you columns at each breakpoints you will surely achieve what you are looking for. You can force the content to stay inline by specifying width = 12 / # elements. And force then to stack by using width = 12....

```
<div class="card-deck">

<div class="card mb-4">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap" />
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Test information</h4>
        <div class="fee-stats">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> TAKER <br /> 0.05% </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> MAKER <br /> 0.05% </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> WITHDRAWL <br /> 0.0005 <span className="bitcoin-icon">&#8383;</span>{" "} </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer border-0 rounded-bottom">
        <small class="text-muted">Intermediate</small>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="card mb-4">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap" />
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Test information</h4>
        <div class="fee-stats">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> TAKER <br /> 0.05% </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> MAKER <br /> 0.05% </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> WITHDRAWL <br /> 0.0005 <span className="bitcoin-icon">&#8383;</span>{" "} </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer border-0 rounded-bottom">
        <small class="text-muted">Intermediate</small>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="card mb-4">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap" />
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Test information</h4>
        <div class="fee-stats">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> TAKER <br /> 0.05% </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> MAKER <br /> 0.05% </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4  px-1">
                        <p class="card-text"> WITHDRAWL <br /> 0.0005 <span className="bitcoin-icon">&#8383;</span>{" "} </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer border-0 rounded-bottom">
        <small class="text-muted">Intermediate</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

*edit*: a link to bootstrap grid system [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).
Here col-6 means it is size 6 (over 12) by default. And col-md-4 says its size 4 as soon as the screen is bigger than medium.

*edit2*: a functioning example [codereply](https://codeply.com/v/vS8D5COalI)

Comment: thats helpful which class tag should I change here to make width smaller in each breakpoint? col-3, ocl-md-4 should I create here a new class? or should I change the row?

Comment: Happy to help, so for example  a col-3 says its size 3 (over a total of 12) by default (until it reaches an other breakpoint (small to big)
Then a col-md-6 says it is size 6 as soon as the screen is bigger than medium..
Hope it helps

Comment: I just realized what you asked sorry: if you want to make columns narrower, you change the width value. from col-6 to col-3 for example, then instead of taking half of the width, it will take 1/4

Comment: your functioning example is just a upload form. I tried with the settings you mentioned and uploaded the difference and breakpoints. It looks even more chaotic than before. Also at the top you see how it should look like. Is this really so difficult to do? I would be happy to change at every breakpoint the width but it seems bootstrap is really complicate here: https://imgur.com/a/krnPVM8

Comment: I updated my "functioning" example. I personally don't modify breakpoints, pretty sure I can't help you with that. I only use bootstrap default ones. If you want things to stack put width of 12, If you want them to form a line put a width of 12 / #items .
I am sorry, I can't figure out your issue exactly but I hope you find your answers

Comment: If you problem is on the card alignment but keeping the inside the same, my codereply should be correct

Comment: hey thanks man thats nearly correct. Just the tablet breakpoint is having a problem with withdrawal, for me it is displayed as: WITHD <br/> RAWL <br/> 0.0005 ₿ How would I change that with bootstrap?

Comment: I would either reduce margins, or change the breakpoint such that it goes to stacked earlier. I guess there is a lot of ways to tackle that behaviour

Comment: I changed the breakpoints and it works thanks! Could you explain the px-1 in the col-4 class? This workflow isn't explained in the doc and from changing it in the code I don't really get what exactly it does, but it fixes the problem

Comment: Hey, nice to hear ! px-1 sets the padding on the x axis as stated in the following doc: [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 0):

On your container your writing col-sm.You don't specify the number. You should add col-sm-4 if you want to break this row on 3 columns.

if you want on all devices to be 3 columns use col-3

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/nhw6Lt10/)

```
 <div class="row">
              <div class="col-3">
                <p class="card-text">
                  TAKER
                  <br />
                  0.05%
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3">
                <p class="card-text">
                  MAKER <br /> 0.05%
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3">
                <p class="card-text">
                  WITHDRAWL
                  <br /> 0.0005
                  <span class="bitcoin-icon">&#8383;</span>{" "}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I tried this alread it doesn't solve the problem. And while doing so it makes it even worse. In mobile version it stacks every letter under each other

Comment: Use col-3 to be on 3 columns on all devices. I update my answer with a working example

Comment: I actually tried that in your working example the text is still stacking horizontally instead of the being vertically aligned like in the desktop version. Also I tried both col-3 and col-sm-3 in my code rendering difference can be seen here: https://imgur.com/a/tLufuNa

In Ipad breakpoint the cards are dragging down extremely because of the -3